# How to loop back to original select menu from a case within a case statement?

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script called q.txt. I want to run a select statement with a case statement. How can I re-display the menu options after `a)` case has been run. `. /home/chh1/q.txt` won't run after `echo "a"` in case `a)`.

It is clear to me why this does not work but is there a way to loop back to the original select menu after a case has been executed?

```
#!/bin/bash

select x in a b c d

do

case $x in
        a) echo "a"
           . /home/chh1/q.txt;;
        b) echo "b";;
        c) echo "c";;
        d) echo "You are now exiting the program"
           break;;
        *) echo "Invalid entry. Please try an option on display";;

esac

done
```

Comment: Please explain "`. /home/chh1/q.txt` won't run". It should run if the path is right. `$0` should be the right path. I used `. "$0"` and it works for me. This approach nests the `select … do … done` loops, I don't think you want this. Still, "won't run" seems false in general.

Comment: Thanks Kamil ```. "$0"``` works. I was working with the wrong path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an outer loop driven by a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
anew=yes
while [ "$anew" = yes ]; do
   anew=no
   select x in a b c d
   do
      case $x in
         a) echo "a"
            anew=yes
            break;;
         b) echo "b";;
         c) echo "c";;
         d) echo "You are now exiting the program"
            break;;
         *) echo "Invalid entry. Please try an option on display";;
      esac
   done
done
```

The initial `anew=yes` makes the `while` loop execute at least once. Inside the loop the variable is set to `no`, then a slightly modified version of your `select` loop is executed. The idea is: when the script exits the `select` loop, the variable should be either `yes` or `no`, and the body of the `while` loop should be repeated or not, respectively. The case `a` simply sets the variable to `yes` and breaks the `select` loop.